# How do i use an aggregation pipeline to identify orders which do not have descriptions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have 2 collections which have 2 fields, i.e. `orderID` and `productCode` which are the keys that form the primary keys
in  2 collections, `orders` and `productInfo`. The keys `orderID` and `productCode` are present in both collections. I want to be able to find `orders` whose `description`s are present. The `description` for any `order` is present if both its `orderID` and `productCode` are present in the `productInfo` collection.

For example, `"apples"` and `"oranges"` have `description`s in the `productInfo` collection, but `"bananas"` and `"milk"` do not. I want to be able to return
the `orderID` and `productCode` for items which do not have `description`s.

I read that I can use an aggregation pipeline to join the
collections but despite looking at examples, I am not able to find out how to use the 2 keys to accomplish this.
I am very new to using mongodb so I'd appreciate if someone could help me. I know I can use a lookup but I discovered that I can only use one localField per lookup and that makes it difficult to figure out. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me figure this out.
I also saw the way to match using $ne but my limited knowledge makes it hard to see how to apply.
Here are the collections in question:

Orders collection

```json
      db.orders.insertMany( [

     { "_id" : 1102, "orderID" : 10340, "productCode": 1, "item" : "apple" },

     { "_id" : 3332, "orderID" : 10341, "productCode": 2,  "item" : "banana"},

     { "_id" : 3443, "orderID" : 10342, "productCode": 3, "item" : "orange" },

     { "_id" : 4332, "orderID" : 10343, "productCode": 4, "item" : "milk" }
   
    ] )
```

And here is the productInfo collection

```json
    db.productInfo.insertMany( [

 
    { "_id" : 1102, "orderID" : 10340, "productCode": 2,  "description" : "granny smith apples"},


    { "_id" : 3443, "orderID" : 10342, "productCode": 4, "description" : "blood oranges from Florida" }
   
  ] )
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `"_id"` values must be unique within a collection, but there are repeats in the `productInfo` collection.  Are you sure what's in your collections?

Comment: My bad, I copied and pasted part of the table and accidentally duplicated the rows. The composite index is  (orderID, productCode}{

Comment: _"I want to be able to find orders whose descriptions are present."_ and _"I want to be able to return the `orderID` and `productCode` for items which do not have descriptions."_?  Also note that there are no matches between your example collections.

Comment: There won't be matches for items that are not present in the productInfo collection.  So, is there no way to solve this type using the aggregation pipeline? If this was a SQL problem, I could solve it using 'where not exists ' etc. So there is not way to use a match with $ne for example. I am not very familar with the pipeline so I am limited in my knowledge.

Comment: _"I want to be able to return the `orderID` and `productCode` for items which do not have descriptions"_. Do I understand it correctly that you want to filter collection `productInfo` to get `orderID` and `productCode` for records  whose `description` is not provided ? @BreenDeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and comments, I think you want:

*"I want to be able to return the `orderID` and `productCode` for items which do not have descriptions."* ... *"The description for any order is present if both its `orderID` and `productCode` are present in the productInfo collection."*

Here's one way to do that.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "productInfo",
      "let": {
        "orderID": "$orderID",
        "productCode": "$productCode"
      },
      "as": "productInfo",
      "pipeline": [
        { // look for matches in productInfo
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {"$eq": ["$orderID", "$$orderID"]},
                {"$eq": ["$productCode", "$$productCode"]}
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { // if matched, no need to return everything
          "$project": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { // match when no productInfo found
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [{"$size": "$productInfo"}, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  { // output requested fields
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "orderID": 1,
      "productCode": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hh9VJbDcNfy).

Comment: Why do we need to match first?  I do not understand how the second match works with the first match. I'd be grateful if you could explain how the 2 matches work together. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @BreenDeen  The first `"$match"` is part of the `"$lookup"` pipeline.  Effectively, this `"$match"` operates within the `productInfo` collection.  I.e., documents in the `productInfo` collection will only pass this "$match"` stage if the given condition is true. The second `"$match"` is back in the `orders` collection, just after the field `"productInfo"` was defined/assigned.  Effectively, it just checks to see if anything made it past the first `"$match"`.